# Create ImageButton programatically depending on local database records

Tags: android, sqlite

As i described in title, i have a local db in sqlite. I want to create `ImageButton` parametrically. How many times is local database loop executing? Please see code below :

```
    RelativeLayout outerRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout2_making_dynamically);
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAllLocal_Job_Data();
    if(c!=null){
         if(c.moveToFirst()){
                do {

                    RelativeLayout innerRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(CalendarActivity.this);
                    innerRelativeLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                    ImageButton imgBtn = new ImageButton(CalendarActivity.this);
                    imgBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.color_001);

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams imageViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    imgBtn.setLayoutParams(imageViewParams);

                    // Adding the textView to the inner RelativeLayout as a child
                    innerRelativeLayout.addView(imgBtn, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                    outerRelativeLayout.addView(innerRelativeLayout, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                } while (c.moveToNext());
         }
    }

    db.close();
```

But when i run the project, i can see only one button created there. I think there are many buttons but here image button is creating on last created image button. I think i should use `android:layout_toRightOf` with previous created button but i cant find how to place it here. I have tried some ideas but it did not change any thing. So please anybody has any idea to solve my problem then please share it with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating multiple ImageButtons correctly, but you're adding them to a relative layout into the same place (specifically, adding inner relative layout to the outer relative layout). I don't know what layout you are trying to achieve, but you can just try changing the outer layout to be LinearLayout.

Further, you don't really need the inner layout - you can add ImageButtons directly to the outer layout.  You may end up with a code like this:

in XML

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/making_dynamically" ... >
```

and then

```
LinearLayout outerLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.making_dynamically);
db.open();
Cursor c = db.getAllLocal_Job_Data();
if(c!=null){
     if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                ImageButton imgBtn = new ImageButton(CalendarActivity.this);
                imgBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.color_001);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                outerLayout.addView(imgBtn, imageViewParams);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
     }
}

db.close();
```

Comment: its really nice way to create ui dynamically...you save my much time........thank you sir..... thank you very much........

Comment: sir, i have one question : now what should i do if i want to add textview in center of the imageButton, i mean i have already add textview dynamical y in my code but by which property should i use so text view come in center of ImageButton ?

Comment: @user2507920 I'm not too sure why you'd want to do that, to be honest.  However if instead of each ImageButton you want a combination of image button and another control, I suggest you create an XML with that combination, then in a loop inflate that XML and add to the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are able to create dynamic buttons according to database but to manage that you need to have  manageable layout you can also create dynamic layout according to your buttons you can use Table layout which would be much better in this case

This is the one to crate dynamic table layout-

```
     TableRow tableRow = null;
     TextView textView = null;
     ImageView imageView = null;
     TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
     RelativeLayout relativeLayout = null;

    for (String string: listOfStrings)
    {
        tableRow = new TableRow(this);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.row, null);
        textView = (TextView) relativeLayout.getChildAt(0);
        textView.setText(string);
        imageView= (ImageView) relativeLayout.getChildAt(1);
        imageView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.blue);

        //Here's where I would add the parameters...
        TableLayout.LayoutParams rlParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(FILL_PARENT,      
        WRAP_CONTENT);
        tableRow.addView(relativeLayout, rlParams);
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
```

Or

```
TableLayout top = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.top_table_layout);
        TableLayout bottom = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottom_table_layout);
        TableLayout main = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);

        TableRow top_row = new TableRow(Guesspic.this);
        TableRow bottom_row = new TableRow(Guesspic.this);
        TableRow main_row = new TableRow(Guesspic.this);

        bottom_row.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams(
                android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        top_row.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams(
                android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        main_row.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams(
                android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        Button below_button1 = new Button(Guesspic.this);
        below_button1.setText("A");
        below_button1.setTag(8);
        below_button1.setLayoutParams(new android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams(
                60, 60));

            top.addView(below_button1);
```

hear you can have taken layout params to maintain the layouts

if this will not work then try to add Margins to the position of every single button

```
innerRelativeLayout.addView(imgBtn, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,       
   ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

after this add---

```
   imageViewParams.setMargins(30, 20, 30, 0);
```

Hope this could help you..